# Filter posts by their post-type with dropdown menu

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I want to filter posts by their post-type.
therefore I have created a dropdown menu where I can select one or multiple post-types.
My question now is: How do I get functionality for my dropdown, because I dont't know how to corespond with the database when the element is in the frontend.

[This is my Dropdown-Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFKpe.png)

Answer (score 0):

Using **ajax** you can filter post.

This is my code for **filter post by category** (filter post by multiple category selection)

ajax code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

  $('.categorytag').click(function(){

  var cokeValue = //you need to pass array of post category id 
      var data = {
            action: 'get_partiblog',
            foo:    cokeValue
        };
      $.post('/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',data,function(response){
         $('#filteredblog').html(response); 
      });
  })
</script>
```

php code

```
<?php
  add_action('wp_ajax_get_partiblog','Getblogcatwise');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_partiblog','Getblogcatwise');

function Getblogcatwise(){
      $catids = $_POST['foo'];
foreach($catids as $catid){
     $args = array(
        'post_type'=> 'post',
        'orderby'    => 'ID',
        'category_name' => $catid,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'order'    => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page' =>-1 // this will retrive all the post that is published 
        );
        $result = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $result-> have_posts() ) : 
         while ( $result->have_posts() ) : $result->the_post(); 
             $link = get_permalink();
            echo '<a href="'.$link.'" target="_blank">';
            echo '<div class="service-wrapper" style="border:1px solid #367bae;">';

           /* if ( has_post_thumbnail() ){

            echo '<div><img src="'.the_post_thumbnail("thumbnail").'"  alt="Image Missing" rel="lightbox"></div>';
            }else{
            echo '<div><img src="https://uae.microless.com/cdn/no_image.jpg" alt="" rel="lightbox"></div>';
            }*/
              $title= get_the_title();
                echo '<center><div style="color:#367bae;font-size:22px;font-weight:700;position: relative;margin-top: 25%;padding:5%;">'.$title.'</div></center>';
          echo '<div class="service-wrapper-inner">';
          //$title= get_the_title();
          //echo '<h3>'.$title.'</h3>';
           echo '<center><i style="font-size:18px;color:#fff;-webkit-transition: 1s;-moz-transition: 1s;-ms-transition: 1s;-o-transition: 1s; transition: 1s;" class="fa fa-bars"></i></center>';
          $excerpt= the_excerpt();
          echo '<div class="description"><p>'.$excerpt.'</p></div></div></div></a>';
          endwhile; 
          endif; wp_reset_postdata();
          }
}
?>
```